# how to install Kernel patch locally in yocto?

Tags: yocto

I want to how to install a kernel patch in yocto. Please guide me

I have included couple of printk statement in **calibrate.c** file which is located in /home/host/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/3.8-r0/linux-3.8/init/calibrate.c

then i have created a patch file using 
diff -Nuar ~/calibrate.c   /home/host/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/3.8-r0/linux-3.8/init/calibrate.c > **calibrate.patch**

then placed the calibrat.patch file in *poky/meta/recipies-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers/* directory

then I have edited the linux-libc-headers_3.8.bb file located in /poky/meta/recipies-kernel/linux-libc-headers/ with the following **SCR_URI = file://calibrate.patch**

Then after executing bitbake -k core-image-minimal i am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Command Error: exit status: 1  Output: Applying patch calibrate.patch can't find file to patch at input line 3 Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option? The text leading up to this was:
-------------------------- |--- calibrate.c 2015-12-09 15:00:11.547924616 +0530 |+++ a/calibrate.c  2015-12-09 14:59:31.387923200 +0530
-------------------------- No file to patch.  Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk ignored

Patch calibrate.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)

ERROR: Function failed: patch_do_patch

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/host/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/3.8-r0/temp/log.do_patch.14062

ERROR: Task 434 (/home/host/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers_3.8.bb, do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 11):

First, the best way to update a recipe in yocto is to create your own, that will be append to the original one. it is the aim of `bbappend` files.
refer to yocto manual to see how to append a recipe. Your layer should approximatively look like this.

```
"your layer's directory"/recipes-kernel/
    => linux-libc-headers/
        => files/
            -> file1.patch
            -> another_file.patch
            -> third_file.patch
        -> linux-libc-headers_3.8.bbappend
```

Second, yocto provides "devshell", which is  a new shell with all yocto's env variable already exported.
Here is how you should work with yocto:

```
bitbake <recipe> -c devshell
```

in your case, it would be

```
bitbake linux-libc-headers -c devshell
```

you'll then have a new shell opened, and you will automatically change into that recipe's workdir.
in your case, /home/host/poky/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-libc-headers/3.8-r0/ or something like that.

if you did not get package from a git repo, then

```
git init
```

and make a dummy commit that will stage all untracked or unstaged changes

```
git add *
git commit -m "dummy"
```

now you can change everything you want. don't forget to commit.
now let's suppose you did 3 commit.
you can create corresponding patches with the following command:

```
git format-patch -3 -o /path/to/anny/directory
```

those patches should (must) be placed in `files` directory located in your recipe's directory (the one you created, not the original one)

```
git format-patch -3 -o /path/to/linux-libc-headers/files/
```

your `linux-libc-headers_3.8.bbappend` should contain something like this

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-Frist-commit.patch"
SRC_URI += "file://0002-Second-commit.patch"
SRC_URI += "file://0003-last-commit.patch"
```

that is all

Comment: hi john, is it possible to apply patch without using git. I am trying to apply the patch locally i.e i will keep the .patch file in my own layer under a directory as you said and add the SRC_URI in the bbappend file,  from there bitbake has to fetch the patch file and apply the patch.

Comment: Instead of using **diff** command to create the patch, using **git diff** enables to create the patch without committing the changes to git and helps in locally applying patch.

Comment: Excellent - this is exactly what I was looking for (in the sea of documentation). Thank you.